# SQL Server Management Studio package could not load correctly

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssms, ssms-2012

I am trying to run SSMS from my local machine. I need to run it as a different user so I can correctly log into the db when doing work. I've created a .bat which runs the file using the following command:

```
@echo off
runas /profile /savecred /user:user "...\Ssms.exe"
```

Which runs it fine, but when trying to open the program as that user, I am getting the following error:

```
The 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.SqlStudioExplorer,
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer, Version=11.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' package did not load correctly.
```

Now I have tried everything under the sun to fix this error. I have tried doing a fresh install, installing a new version of SQL Service Pack. Most things I find online are fixes to the visual studio, but is of no use here.

The version being used is `SQL Server Management Studio 2012`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I, along with everyone else here is stumped.